# PCA + SVM using C++ Syntax in OpenCV 2.2

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, svm, pca

I'm having problems getting PCA and Eigenfaces working using the latest C++ syntax with the Mat and PCA classes. The older C syntax took an array of IplImage* as a parameter to perform its processing and the current API only takes a Mat that is formatted by Column or Row. I took the Row approach using the reshape function to fit my image's matrix to fit in a single row. I eventually want to take this data and then use the SVM algorithm to perform detection, but when I do that all my data is just a stream of 0s. Can someone please help me out? What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4661903/pca-in-opencv-using-the-new-c-interface) and it's somewhat related, but I'm not sure what the solution is.

This is basically what I have:

```
vector<Mat> images; //This variable will be loaded with a set of images to perform PCA on.
Mat values(images.size(), 1, CV_32SC1); //Values are the corresponding values to each of my images.

int nEigens = images.size() - 1; //Number of Eigen Vectors.

//Load the images into a Matrix
Mat desc_mat(images.size(), images[0].rows * images[0].cols, CV_32FC1);
for (int i=0; i<images.size(); i++) {
  desc_mat.row(i) = images[i].reshape(1, 1);
}

Mat average;
PCA pca(desc_mat, average, CV_PCA_DATA_AS_ROW, nEigens);

Mat data(desc_mat.rows, nEigens, CV_32FC1); //This Mat will contain all the Eigenfaces that will be used later with SVM for detection

//Project the images onto the PCA subspace
for(int i=0; i<images.size(); i++) {
  Mat projectedMat(1, nEigens, CV_32FC1);
  pca.project(desc_mat.row(i), projectedMat);

  data.row(i) = projectedMat.row(0);
}

CvMat d1 = (CvMat)data;
CvMat d2 = (CvMat)values;

CvSVM svm;
svm.train(&d1, &d2);
svm.save("svmdata.xml");
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What etarion said is correct.

To copy a column or row you always have to write:

```
Mat B = mat.col(i);
A.copyTo(B);
```

The following program shows how to perform a PCA in OpenCV. It'll show the mean image and the first three Eigenfaces. The images I used in there are available from http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/research/dtg/attarchive/facedatabase.html:

```
#include "cv.h"
#include "highgui.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

Mat normalize(const Mat& src) {
    Mat srcnorm;
    normalize(src, srcnorm, 0, 255, NORM_MINMAX, CV_8UC1);
    return srcnorm;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    vector<Mat> db;

    // load greyscale images (these are from http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/research/dtg/attarchive/facedatabase.html)
    db.push_back(imread("s1/1.pgm",0));
    db.push_back(imread("s1/2.pgm",0));
    db.push_back(imread("s1/3.pgm",0));

    db.push_back(imread("s2/1.pgm",0));
    db.push_back(imread("s2/2.pgm",0));
    db.push_back(imread("s2/3.pgm",0));

    db.push_back(imread("s3/1.pgm",0));
    db.push_back(imread("s3/2.pgm",0));
    db.push_back(imread("s3/3.pgm",0));

    db.push_back(imread("s4/1.pgm",0));
    db.push_back(imread("s4/2.pgm",0));
    db.push_back(imread("s4/3.pgm",0));

    int total = db[0].rows * db[0].cols;

    // build matrix (column)
    Mat mat(total, db.size(), CV_32FC1);
    for(int i = 0; i < db.size(); i++) {
        Mat X = mat.col(i);
        db[i].reshape(1, total).col(0).convertTo(X, CV_32FC1, 1/255.);
    }

    // Change to the number of principal components you want:
    int numPrincipalComponents = 12;

    // Do the PCA:
    PCA pca(mat, Mat(), CV_PCA_DATA_AS_COL, numPrincipalComponents);

    // Create the Windows:
    namedWindow("avg", 1);
    namedWindow("pc1", 1);
    namedWindow("pc2", 1);
    namedWindow("pc3", 1);

    // Mean face:
    imshow("avg", pca.mean.reshape(1, db[0].rows));

    // First three eigenfaces:
    imshow("pc1", normalize(pca.eigenvectors.row(0)).reshape(1, db[0].rows));
    imshow("pc2", normalize(pca.eigenvectors.row(1)).reshape(1, db[0].rows));
    imshow("pc3", normalize(pca.eigenvectors.row(2)).reshape(1, db[0].rows));

    // Show the windows:
    waitKey(0);
}
```

and if you want to build the matrix by row (like in your original question above) use this instead:

```
// build matrix
Mat mat(db.size(), total, CV_32FC1);
for(int i = 0; i < db.size(); i++) {
    Mat X = mat.row(i);
    db[i].reshape(1, 1).row(0).convertTo(X, CV_32FC1, 1/255.);
}
```

and set the flag in the PCA to:

```
CV_PCA_DATA_AS_ROW
```

Regarding machine learning. I wrote a document on machine learning with the OpenCV C++ API that has examples for most of the classifiers, including Support Vector Machines. Maybe you can get some inspiration there: http://www.bytefish.de/pdf/machinelearning.pdf.

Answer (score 4):

```
data.row(i) = projectedMat.row(0);
```

This will not work. `operator=` is a shallow copy, meaning no data is actually copied. Use

```
cv::Mat sample = data.row(i); // also a shallow copy, points to old data!
projectedMat.row(0).copyTo(sample);
```

The same also for:

```
desc_mat.row(i) = images[i].reshape(1, 1);
```

Comment: Does it matter that it's only a shallow copy? It will just update the pointer to that set of data, which still should be usable. Correct?

Comment: @rsnj: It does matter because that statement is essentially a no-op. `data.row(i)` creates a new matrix header that points to the same data, now `operator=` modifies this new returned matrix header and does nothing else, and at the end of the expression the temporary matrix header (that you modified) gets destructed. `data` is completely unmodified. the opencv manual explicitely states that this "doesn't work".

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest looking at the newly checked in tests in svn head

modules/core/test/test_mat.cpp

online here : https://code.ros.org/svn/opencv/trunk/opencv/modules/core/test/test_mat.cpp

has examples for PCA  in the old c and new c++

Hope that helps!

Comment: I've been looking at the tests and I think I'm more confused than I was before. I see they use a Random Number Generator to construct their Matrix to perform PCA on. Am I correct to assume that my approach on reshaping my Image Mat's and adding them to the rows of a new Mat is the correct approach? The thing that really confuses me between the C and C++ version is the C accepts an array of images (or Matrix) and the C++ version only accepts a single Matrix. Thanks!