# OpenCV 2.2 PCA and EigenFaces

Tags: opencv, pca, pattern-recognition

I just wanted to know if the cv::PCA::PCA constructor method in OpenCV 2.2 makes the substraction of the mean, or if I must pass my data already with the mean subtracted.

I tested both ways, but when visualizing eigenfaces neither of them are giving me good results but just a black screen. I have no segmentations faults or errors, I just don't get the eigenfaces visualization as in the papers.

Answer (score 4):

I posted a complete example that shows how to use the PCA and display Eigenfaces here: [PCA + SVM using C++ Syntax in OpenCV 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4974709/pca-svm-using-c-syntax-in-opencv-2-2) (and on my page: http://www.bytefish.de/blog/pca_in_opencv).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that they substract the mean within the PCA functions (i went to see the declaration of cv::PCA). Anyway I can't get eigenfaces visualization, it is just a black window. What I thought was that they weren't normalized, but no, I printed the L2 norm of each eigenvector and it is exactly 1.

Answer (score -1):

I think to get eigenfaces you need to project the PCA eigenvector to an image.

Comment: This is not the problem, I actually convert the eigenvectors to a two dimensional array of the same size of my images (all of them are 200x200) and display them, resulting in a black screen. Also the problem is not the bit depth or something related, I checked that too, I made a test by reconstructing one of the images back from the PCA data eigenvectors, and the resulting image resembles the original, obviously not exactly because of the loss of information when projecting to the EigenSpace, but it displayed well.