# PCA Project and Backproject in OpenCV 2.3 (C++)

Tags: c++, opencv, face-recognition, pca

I'm working on a face recognition project and I am having problems when projecting on PCA subspace.

When I pass a mat vector to my funcion with the resized images, I project them, and then I reconstruct them to verify it's working well, but all I have in "Cam" window is a grey image (all same color).

I don't know what I am doing bad.

This is the function:

```
void doPCA (const vector<Mat>& images)
{
int nEigens = images.size()-1;
Mat data (images.size(), images[0].rows*images[0].cols, images[0].type() );
for (int i = 0; i < images.size(); i++)
{
Mat aux = data.row(i);
images[i].reshape(1,1).copyTo(aux);
}
PCA pca(data,Mat(),CV_PCA_DATA_AS_ROW,nEigens);

//Project images
Mat dataprojected(data.rows, nEigens, CV_32FC1) ;
for(int i=0; i<images.size(); i++)
{
pca.project(data.row(i), dataprojected.row(i));
}

//Backproject to reconstruct images
Mat datareconstructed (data.rows, data.cols, data.type());
for(int i=0; i<images.size(); i++)
{
pca.backProject (dataprojected.row(i), datareconstructed.row(i) );
}
for(int i=0; i<images.size(); i++)
{
imshow ("Cam", datareconstructed.row(i).reshape(1,images[0].rows) );
waitKey();
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this post is a duplicate of:

- [PCA + SVM using C++ Syntax in OpenCV 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4974709/pca-svm-using-c-syntax-in-opencv-2-2)

Ah, I have found the error in your code. When you create the data matrix you do:

```cpp
images[i].reshape(1,1).copyTo(aux);
```

You have to use convertTo to convert the data into the correct type and copy it to your data matrix:

```cpp
images[i].reshape(1,1).convertTo(aux, CV_32FC1, 1/255.);
```

Then the normalized eigenvectors should be ok. And don't forget to to normalize the values between 0 and 255 before displaying them, you can use [cv::normalize](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/operations_on_arrays.html#cv-normalize) to do this, here's a simple function for turning it into grayscale:

```cpp
Mat toGrayscale(const Mat& src) {
    Mat srcnorm;
    cv::normalize(src, srcnorm, 0, 255, NORM_MINMAX, CV_8UC1);
    return srcnorm;
}
```

You may want to look at the example in my blog:

- http://bytefish.de/blog/pca_in_opencv#simple_example

Comment: Hi bytefish.First of all, thanks. I tryied with "normalize" but it doesn't work, so I rewrite my code to use your algorithm (simple example) and if I show the pca.mean and the eigenvectors all I see is a black image.

Comment: Please try if convertTo solves your problem (I've edited my answer). By the way, I am providing an Eigenfaces and Fisherfaces implementation on my page, if that is what you are after.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Finally I am using your code "Simple Example" that is on your blog and it worked well. I will check the rest of your blog. Thanks again.