# Unhandled Exception while assigning martix elements

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a vector of images defined as bellow:

```
 vector<Mat> src;
```

I want to store each image in this vector as a separate row in a Mat. So the result Mat will be a (n*m) matrix with n being the number of images and m, dimension of images.

```
Mat reData;
for(int i = 0; i < src.size(); i++) {
    if(src[i].empty()) {
        string error_message = format("Image number %d was empty, please check your input data.", i);
        CV_Error(CV_StsBadArg, error_message);
    }
    // Make sure data can be reshaped, throw a meaningful exception if not!
    if(src[i].total() != src[0].total()) {
        string error_message = format("Wrong number of elements in matrix #%d! Expected %d was %d.", i, src[0].total(), src[i].total());
        CV_Error(CV_StsBadArg, error_message);
    }
    Mat xi;
    if(src[i].isContinuous()) {
        xi= src[i].reshape(1, 1);
    } else {
        xi= src[i].clone().reshape(1, 1);
    }

    for(int j=0; j< src[0].total(); j++)
    {
        try{
        reData.at<float>(i,j)=xi.at<float>(0,j);
        }
        catch (cv::Exception const & e) { std::cerr<<"OpenCV exception: "<<e.what()<<std::endl; }
    }
}
```

when run my code, Will produce the following exception when running `reData.at<float>(i,j)=xi.at<float>(0,j);`:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x000007f68e0d1e1d in code.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000001f5f000.
```

This exception What am I doing wrong?

**Update 1**

The way i defined reData Mat in previous code is wrong. I changed definition:

```
Mat reData(src.size(), src[0].total(), src[0].type());
```

Comment: An access violation is not a C++ exception.

Comment: _'What am I doing wrong?'_ You're using an uninitialized pointer most probably.

Comment: @iMoses- did i said that access violation is a c++ exception?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ- I have defined reData with `Mat reData(src.size(), src[0].total(), src[0].type());`why i'm using uninitialized pointer?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: that comment is not really helpful. It does not help anything with solving the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Mat xi** is empty.The Matr is declared the variable, but not given it any memory. That causes the access violation. I've done the same thing myself a hundred times.

Create a matrix of ones. Something like:

```
Mat xi =  Mat::ones(100, 100, CV_8U);
```

But substitute your own values.

Comment: thank you, as you said the problem was xi was not given memory. So i used `copyTo` function and the problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

After searching several threads i found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4974709/pca-svm-using-c-syntax-in-opencv-2-2) about training svm using pca features.
The second answer contains nice solution for avoiding these kind of exceptions. Actually  `operator=` is a shallow copy, meaning no data is actually copied. So i changed my code and it runs without any problem.

```
src[i].reshape(1, 1).copyTo(xi);
```

**Wrong** way to assign matrix elements:

```
xi= src[i].reshape(1, 1);
```